# Passing a file path as an argument in a command

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

I’m trying to pass a file path as an argument to a command.  I’m using lualatex and I can’t quite figure out how to get it to work.  The new command I defined is:

```
\newcommand{\ScoreWithTranslation}[2]
{
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    \gresetheadercapture{initial-style}{gresetinitiallines}{}
    \gresetheadercapture{commentary}{grecommentary}{}
    \gregorioscore{#1}\switchcolumn
    #2\switchcolumn
\end{paracol}
}
```

I’m then trying to use the command to access a score file that is in a separate directory:

```
\ScoreWithTranslation{/filefolder/score}{translation text}
```

However, when I use this command I get an error that says it can’t find the folder when using TexShop.  When using Overleaf it just skips over it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Problem solved...  apparently I space the command out on separate lines.

Comment: To make sure that the command also works with file-paths that contain `%` or `#` or `}` or `{` or the like you can probably define it using the xparse-package's `\NewDocumentCommand{\ScoreWithTranslation}{vm}{<some definition text with arguments #1 and #2>}`, `v` denoting a verbatim-argument, `m` denoting a normal undelimited argument. ;-)

Comment: Depending on the platform in use you may need to wrap file-paths (with spaces) in quotes. Besides this ensure that you have/TeX has the rights needed for accessing the files in question.